# how to push git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, gitlab

I need some help with git branches. I do not think i understand the procedure at all, as I keep getting confused.

What I want is to make a simple branch, from which I can fix an issue on my website without erasing all the things I've worked on so far. I have moved so far away from what I have on my production server, that I cant easily tidy up my code to prevent breaking the site.

So I have tried in several ways to make a new branch, but things keep giving me errors and such.
For example, I saw somewhere that you can create a tag, and then turn it into a branch. Which I have. I successfully tagged the commit I wanted my branch to work from, then i made the new branch, and sure enough I now have two heads "master" and my new branch. However, in the gitlab page, I cannot see any new branches... And pushing up to the server gives me some errors that I can't exactly figure out why they occur.

it gives me this log when i try to push:

```
Counting objects: 97, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (51/51), 21.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 51 (delta 39), reused 35 (delta 25)
remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:33:in `eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)
remote: /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
remote: gem "mysql2", group: :mysql
remote:                     ^
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:19:in `build'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
remote:     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To https://gitlab.repo.com/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.repo.com/repo.git'
```

will someone please help me? I couldn't find anything that is specific to my situation, so Im sorry if I have missed out on any duplicates and such.

**Update** I no longer have this problem, and I the way this was solved is rather irrelevant to the current question. Thanks to anyone who commented :)

Comment: That has nothing to do with Git. You have a hook in your gitlab server which is rejecting Ruby code containing invalid syntax, and it seems to be using an ancient Ruby which doesn't understand the new hash syntax.

Comment: Yes meagar has right, check your Gemfile (i think group is not with : at end).

Comment: You seem to be right... Although I have no idea what this problem could have stemmed from. I did it again from scratch, and it seemed to work that time. Im a little confused. Oh well it seems to be fine for now, and that's important.